# Prevent state from updating if input string has spaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my code below? basically I don't want to update my state when user enter extra space at the beginning or at the end.

```
handleSearchQuery = (e) = {
  if(e.target.value.trim() != "") {
    this.setState({
      q: e.target.value
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple solution - `handleSearchQueury = (e) => this.setState({ q: e.target.value.trim() })`

Comment: @NirH, that will cause a re-render even if the new (trimmed) value is equal to the old.

Comment: It won't, I advise to read a bit about the virtual-dom and reconciliation - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error seems to be that you forgot a `>` in your arrow function. Change the first line to:

```
handleSearchQuery = (e) => {
```

---

Anyway, this is how I would write the whole function:

```
handleSearchQuery = (e) => {
  let str = e.target.value.trim();
  if(str != this.state.q) {
    this.setState({
      q: str
    });
  }
}
```

This compares the trimmed input to the existing state of `q`. If they are equal, nothing happens. Otherwise, update the state.

I store the trimmed result of the string in a variable as I would otherwise need to `trim()` twice... for whatever that's worth.

Comment: ouch careless mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSearchQuery = (e) => {
  if(e.target.value.trim() != this.state.q) {
    this.setState({
      q: e.target.value
    });
  }
}
```